# make the cube hide for seconds and appear it again for seconds unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

is there a simple UnityScript code to hide and unhide a cube 
or any other gameobjects for a particular time ?

```
//make the object invisible
renderer.enabled = false;

// make the object visible
renderer.enabled = true;

// toggle object's visibility each second
function Update () {

// Find out whether current second is odd or even
var seconds : int = Time.time;


// Enable renderer accordingly
renderer.enabled = oddeven;
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to hide the object, fire off a coroutine that waits for N seconds, and then unhide.

This is C#, the conversion to Javascript should be simple but I don't think JS uses **startCoroutine** ([This page](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/Coroutines.html) in the docs explains the difference between the C# and Javascript versions).

```
public bool Hide = false;


void Update()
{
    if (Hide && renderer.enabled) {
        renderer.enabled = false;
        Hide = false;
        StartCoroutine("WaitUnhide");
    }
}


IEnumerator WaitUnhide()
{  
    yield return (new WaitForSeconds(2));
    renderer.enabled = true;
}
```

In this version you would set the 'hide' variable from some other code to start the hiding.  `Hide && renderer.enabled` means you can't kick off a new hide until the old one completes - that's not the only way to do it but it avoids having multiple hide/unhides overlapping.

To make it loop forever:

```
  void Start()
  {  
    StartCoroutine("HideUnhide");
   }


  IEnumerator HideUnhide()
  {
    while (true) {
        yield return (new WaitForSeconds(2));
        renderer.enabled = true;
        yield return (new WaitForSeconds(2));
        renderer.enabled = false;
        }

  }
```

Comment: I want it to loop like hide, unhide , hide, unhide for a seconds .

Comment: Thanks A lot mister theodox :)

Answer (score 1):

To show/hide a game object, rather than using render.enabled property, you should use

```
// Deactivates the game object.
gameObject.SetActive (false);
```

More details can be found [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GameObject.SetActive.html).

To call this function periodically, as theodox said, [startCoroutine](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html) is your friend.

Comment: Will the gameObject still update if SetActive is off?